# Can't get my Google Apps script on Sheets to trigger automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made myself a code for Google Sheets that sends me an automatic email whenever a condition is met.
I have managed to make this work, but only when I manually edit the sheet - I need it to trigger automatically when the sheet changes itself.

My Sheet manages my subscriptions for my clients, whenever the cell on the first column goes to the number 3 - that row is marked as "impending" - and ideally sends me the email.
(The number 3 automatically appears whenever the expiry date of that item is under 2 weeks).

Please let me know if you think you can spot where I haven't set thing up properly :)
Thanks!

**In Google Apps Script I've tried setting the trigger** (but can't get it to be automatic)

```
Choose which function to run
sendMailEdit

Which runs at deployment
Head

Select event source
From spreadsheet

Select event type
On edit (also tried On change)
```

**And here's my code:**

```
    function sendMailEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value !=3) return;
  const rData = e.source.getSheetByName('SUBSCRIPTIONS').getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,14).getValues();

  let mis = rData[0][1];
  let dat = new Date(rData[0][2]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  let cos = rData[0][3];
  let aut = rData[0][4];
  let typ = rData[0][5];
  let des = rData[0][6];
  let pro = rData[0][7];
  let not = rData[0][8];
  let cnu = rData[0][9];
  let cna = rData[0][10];
  let sta = rData[0][13];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");

  
  let msg = ":: AUTOMATED EMAIL FROM - NP PROJECTS SHEET 2021 / SUBSCRIPIONS PAGE :: " + "\n" + "\n" + sta + " SUBSCRIPTION FOR: " + "\n" + dat + " (" + mis + " days missing)"  + "\n" + "Cost: " + cos + "$" + "\n" + "Is autopay active: " + aut + "\n" + "\n" +"CLIENT: " + cna + " (" + cnu + ")" + "\n" + "\n" + "Product: " + typ + "\n" + "\n"+"Descprition: " + des  + "\n" + "\n" + "Provider: " + pro  + "\n" + "\n"+ "Notes: " + not  + "\n" + "\n"+ "\n" + "(This email was triggered at:" +  now + ")";
  
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "IMPENDING SUBSCRIPTION (automail)", msg)
}
```

Comment: There is no such trigger.  onEdit triggers only fire on user edits

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started

Comment: Thanks! still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const col = e.range.getColumn()
  const sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()

  // skip if not col 1 or "My Target Sheet" is the sheet name
  if( col != 1 || sheetName != "My Target Sheet") return

  // here you can get the data and send the Email
  // you may need to call a function sendEmail(){} as I am not sure whether you can trigger an email send in the onEdit(e) function

  
}
```

However, if the cell in your sheet contains a formula, then this will not work as nobody has actually edited the sheet, i.e. no event has occurred. If this is the case, then I suggest you create a time-trigger which runs daily (or hourly) and checks to see if any rows have a 3 in column a

```
function report3s(){
  const rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues()
   
   rows.forEach( row => {
     const col_a_value = row[0]
     if( col_a_value != 3 ) return
     
     // do something here
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning, this definitely helps :)

Comment: If the comment helped then mark is as done. Glad I could help.